# Core Data Lazy Loading with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType and custom setter not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, lazy-loading, relationship

**Problem:** Fetching a managed object using a background thread does not lazy load the NSManaged object relationship correctly when the NSManaged object that is related has a custom setter. Doing fetch on main thread with main concurrency type works without a problem. Why is this?

**Work Around:** If I create a custom getter on the relationship object and check for nil, I can force the NSManaged object to load by calling other variables that don't have custom setter methods.

**Background**
The core data layout is pretty simple. I have a Game managed object and a Turn managed object. The turn object is a one to one relationship with the game object. I always fetch the game object in order to access the turn object. TurnImp and GameImp are implementation classes that inherit from the Game and Turn object so I don't put getter/setter methods in auto generated code.

**Code**

*The Fetch*

```
//
//Stick command on background
//
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^ {
    //
    //Load Game 
    //
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    CoreDataHelper *coreDataHelper = appDelegate.coreDataHelper;
    NSManagedObjectContext *childMOC = [coreDataHelper createChildManagedObjectContext];

    //the request
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest new];

    //the object entity we want
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:GAMEIMP_GAME inManagedObjectContext:childMOC];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    //the predicate rules, the what
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"gameId == %@", @"1404110671234567"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    //the sorting rules
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:GAMEIMP_OBJECT_ID ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //Fetch results
    NSFetchedResultsController *resultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:childMOC sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    NSError *error;
    BOOL success = [resultsController performFetch:&error];
    GameImp *game;
    if (success) {
        game = [resultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to get game. Error: %@", error);
    }
    TurnImp *turnImp = game.turn;

    //Issue is here!!! Should be 3, instead 0 because lastRoundReward is nil.
    int lastRoundReward = [turnImp.lastRoundReward intValue];

    //Work around, call custom getter method. Now 3 is returned.
    lastRoundReward = [turnImp getLastRoundReward];
 }
```

*This childMOC creation*

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext*) createChildManagedObjectContext {
   NSManagedObjectContext *childMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]    initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
   childMOC.parentContext = self.mainManagedObjectContext;

   return childMOC;
}
```

*TurnImp Header*

```
@interface TurnImp : Turn

@property(atomic) BOOL isValid;
- (void) setLastRoundReward: (int) lastRoundReward;
- (int) getLastRoundReward;
@end
```

*TurnImp M*

```
@implementation TurnImp

@synthesize isValid;
@synthesize lastRoundReward = _lastRoundReward;

/**
 * Set the last round reward
 * @param -
 * @return -
 */
- (void) setLastRoundReward: (int) lastRoundReward {
    _lastRoundReward = [NSNumber numberWithInt:lastRoundReward];
}

/**
 * Get the int value of lastRoundReward
*/
- (int) getLastRoundReward {
    //Note - HACK! Lazy loading not working, try another member
    if (self.lastRoundReward == nil) {
        //Force load
        NSString *objectId = self.objectId;
    }
    return [self.lastRoundReward intValue];
}
```

*Change childMoc to mainMoc and it works. MainMoc Code*

```
 //create the main MOC
 _mainManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
```

**More After Fixed Concurrency issue**

```
[childMOC performBlock:^{

        // Execute the fetch on the childMOC and do your other work.
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *results = [childMOC executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        if (results == nil) {
            // Handle error
        } else if (results.count == 1) {
            GameImp *game = [results firstObject];
            TurnImp *turnImp = game.turn;

            //Issue is here!!! Should be 3, instead 0 because lastRoundReward is nil.
            int lastRoundReward = [turnImp.lastRoundReward intValue];

            //Work around, call variable objectId (not same as ObjectId)
            NSString *objectId = turnImp.objectId;
            //not it's 3...
            lastRoundReward = [turnImp.lastRoundReward intValue];

        }
    }];
```

**Work Around**

I removed the following from TurnImp and it works as expected with the relationships.

```
@synthesize lastRoundReward = _lastRoundReward;
```

Comment: After glancing a bit more, what is turn2, and how does it fit into the picture?  Also, what is the lastRoundReward?  Is it supposed to be a transient attribute, or what?  Maybe you should show a picture of your model, and their attributes, and explain a bit as to what you are trying to do.  If you are synthesizing an existing core data attribute, that's a no-no as they are dynamic, and will be created at runtime.

Comment: @JodyHagins - Turn2 typo. LastRoundReward is NSNumber, a dynamic on the NSManaged object. I was unaware once again that synthesize on a core data would have been a problem. Was trying for a custom setter/getter. Removing all synthesize fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I have to confess that I have no idea what your problem statement means - what is lazy loading of a relationship supposed to do anyway?

However, a quick glance at your code reveals that you are creating a MOC with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` yet you are not properly wrapping its use inside an appropriate `performBlock` invocation.

When you clearly violate the Core Data Concurrency guidelines, you are playing in dangerous waters and will get undefined behavior.

Also, why create an instance of `NSFetchedResultsController` just to perform a fetch?  That's overkill.  Simply use a fetch request.  Like so...

```
[childMOC performBlock:^{
    // Execute the fetch on the childMOC and do your other work.
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results = [childMOC executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (result == nil) {
        // Handle error
    } else if (results.count == 1) {
        GameImp *game = [results firstObject];
        TurnImp *turnImp = game.turn;
        int lastRoundReward = [turn2.lastRoundReward intValue];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Lazy Loading, core data lazy loads managed objects when using relationships. That's what I meant.

Comment: Yes I obviously violated concurrency. However I made the suggested changes and I still have the same issue. Look at my new additions to question.

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer because Jody's responses got me in the right direction. Two things wound up being wrong, 1.) Miss use of concurrency with core data, 2.) using synthesize on core data objects breaks the lazy loading.

Comment: @LEO - glad you got it working.  I abandoned real life for a bit as my family and our best friends spent several days visiting the worlds of Harry Potter and Mickey Mouse, via the dimensional portal located in Orlando, Florida.